# Using Authlogic to authenticate with only a username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

There's this mother app which is on Java (Struts), which also handles authentication. My Rails app which is being integrated into the mother app uses authlogic. Ofcourse, the requirement is, once someone logs into the mother app, they should automatically be able to access my Rails app without signing in again.

Is there any way, by using just the user id , I can authenticate the user using Authlogic?

I removed my password column in my Users table and stuck this piece of code into the User model.

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.check_passwords_against_database = false
  config.validate_password_field = false
  config.crypted_password_field = false
end
```

But I'm still not able to do what I wanted to do.I get an error indicating that the password can't be blank.Help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass a user object instead of login/password

```
UserSession.new(User.find_by_username('Shreyas Satish'))
```

(This works with rails 3 and authlogic 2.1.6)