# Rails, Authlogic without password (registration ok. user_session validation fails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, authlogic

I am trying to skip the password for Users in Authlogic..

Thanks to SO, I found a solution for creating users

```
 User
 acts_as_authentic do |c|
   c.validate_password_field = false
   c.validate_email_field = false
 end
```

The User_session is still giving a problem - any time I try to log in I get "password cannot be blank"..

how to bypass validation on user session?

Comment: Well.. a little update: I found  authenticating_with_password? in Authlogic's Session/Password.rb  added def authenticating_with_password?
      false
    end  to UserSession model, but still no good..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found it here:

[Using Authlogic to authenticate with only a username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698988/using-authlogic-to-authenticate-with-only-a-username)

Just pass a user object instead of login/password

UserSession.new(User.find_by_username('Shreyas Satish'))
(This works with rails 3 and authlogic 2.1.6)

Thanks to fantactuka!